# What is the difference between k-holdout and k-fold cross validation?

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation

Can some one provide an example on what is k-holdout and k-fold cross validation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically, it's explained on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)#k-fold_cross-validation):

> k-fold cross-validation. In k-fold cross-validation, the original
> sample is randomly partitioned into k equal sized subsamples. Of the k
> subsamples, a single subsample is retained as the validation data for
> testing the model, and the remaining k − 1 subsamples are used as
> training data. The cross-validation process is then repeated k times
> (the folds), with each of the k subsamples used exactly once as the
> validation data.
>
> Holdout method. This can be considered the simplest variation of
> k-fold cross-validation, although it does not cross-validate. We
> randomly assign data points to two sets d0 and d1, usually called the
> training set and the test set, respectively. The size of each of the
> sets is arbitrary although typically the test set is smaller than the
> training set. We then train on d0 and test on d1.

So, simply saying, k-fold creates many randomly chosen subsamples (d1,d2,d3,...), holdout creates one random subsample for validation set (d1).

---

Given a sample with 9 data points:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

3-fold:

```
validation: [1,5,7], training: [2,3,4,6,8,9] 
validation: [2,3,6], training: [1,7,4,5,8,9] 
validation: [4,8,9], training: [2,3,1,6,4,7]
```

$\binom 93 = 84$ (possible) cases overall (for exhaustive case)

9-fold (leave-one-out gives 9 folds) :

```
validation: [2], training: [1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
validation: [3], training: [1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9]
validation: [5], training: ...
validation: [4], training: ...
validation: [6], training: ...
validation: [1], training: ...
validation: [7], training: ...
validation: [9], training: ...
validation: [8], training: ...
```

holdout (validation subsample size = 4):

```
validation: [1,2,7,8], training: [3,4,5,6,9]
(1 subsample overall)
```

Note that holdout uses only one **single** validation-training pair, that's why it doesn't really cross-validate as there is only one subsample.

Basically holdout procedure is same as for choosing a test-set. The only difference is that when you train several models (and several variations of hyper-parameteres) in assembly - you choose a model that performs best on the validation set (minimal validation error), but report test-set error because it's less optimistic.

---

P.S. There is also an important distinction between exhaustive and non-exhaustive cross-validation. There are 84 possible splits for 3-fold of 9 points, but only some small number of subsamples is used in non-exhaustive case, otherwise it would be a "Leave-p-out" (Leave-3-out) cross-validation (it validates all 84 subsamples)

Comment: "In practice, holdout is applied when training set is large enough (maybe hundreds or thousands of data points), so there is no need for cross-validation."

Would you like to explain? is it because its expensive for big dataset?

Comment: "Let's say if you use 10-fold for 1000 data points - it would mean that only  1% of examples are going to be included in your dataset." ??? 10-fold on 1000 cases means that 10 surrogate models are each trained on 900 cases and tested with 100 cases - which IMHO is a totally reasonable way of dealing with 1000 cases.

Comment: I'd have called your "1-fold" "leave-(n-1)-out": the k in k-fold is usually the denominator for the fraction of cases that is tested by each surrogate model: 3-fold => 1/3 of cases are test cases. In that description, 1-fold would mean *all* cases are test cases, whereas training on 1 sample means testing $\frac{n-1}{n} = 1 - \frac{1}{n}$ of the cases, in the example this would be .888-fold in the usual interpretation of k.

Comment: ... and leave (n-1) out is not so strange any more if you deal with clustered data (i.e. there are confounder groups) and want to estimate how well a model trained on one cluster only deals with data from other clusters.

Comment: @cbeleites thank you, you're right - I confused `k` in k-fold with `p` in leave-p-out, corrected it in the answer.